# pushing metrics to statsd from dotnetcore application

Tags: windows, azure, .net-core, statsd

**framework** : dotnetcore 2.0,
**library used** : Graphite.dll 1.3.0 (github url : https://github.com/peschuster/graphite-client), System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.5.0

I am trying to push application metrics to statsd using the following configuration:

1. app.config settings:

> ```
>   <configSections>
>     <section name="graphite" type="Graphite.Configuration.GraphiteConfiguration, Graphite" />
>   </configSections>
>   <graphite xmlns="http://github.com/peschuster/Graphite/Configuration">
>     <statsd address="10.32.2.9" port="8125" prefixKey="dapp.metrics" />
>   </graphite>
> ```

This is working fine from my local machine which is in **windows 8.1**.

Throwing the following exception when hosting it in azure **windows server 2012**:

> *System.InvalidOperationException: statsd pipe is not configured
>   at Graphite.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel(String type, String target, Single sampling
>   at Graphite.MetricsPipe.ReportCounter(String key, Int64 value, Single sampling
>   at MyApplication.GraphiteMetricPublisher.PublishCount(String key)*

In azure **windows server 2016**, no exception is getting thrown but metrics is also not pushed to statsd.

From all the above mentioned machines I am able to push data to statsd using bash script.